# JavaScript for PDF: What is the token beteween words used by getPageNthWord()?

Tags: javascript, pdf

In JavaScript for PDF there is a method used to get the Nth word on a page.

So, what is the token used by getPageNthWord() that separate words?

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace, punctuation marks, newlines and the usual stuff.

Comment: Those are the obvious ones, but... I'm looking for the exact rule.

Comment: Did you try this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf ?